# Blazored Toast not working from the view-model

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm trying to get some toast to appear in a Blazor project using Blazored Toast. Every Blazored Toast example I've been able to find has the toast being called from a button where it's been something like

```
<button class="btn btn-info" @onclick="@(() => toastService.ShowInfo("I'm an INFO message"))">Info Toast</button>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have the toast be called from the C# class view model where I call

```
toastService.ShowSuccess("Here is my message!")
```

However when I try to run the statement, nothing happens - not even an error.

I've been referring to the Blazored Toast github https://github.com/Blazored/Toast and there aren't any answers from what I can see.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Here is some more of my code:

Page.razor

```
@inject PageViewModel vm
<g id="rightButton" class="rightColor" @onclick="Start" disabled="@(!Allowed)">
   ....
</g>
@code{
    public void Start(){
        vm.Apply();
    }

}
```

PageViewModel.cs

```
private Blazored.Toast.Services.ToastService _toastService;

public PageViewModel(IToastService toast){
    this._toastService = toastService as Blazored.Toast.Services.ToastService;
}

public void Apply(){
    this._toastService.ShowSuccess("Here's a toast!");
    //If condition
        this._toastService.ShowSuccess("Condition 1");
    //Else condition
        this._toastService.ShowWarning("Condition 2");
}
```

Comment: Displaying messages should not be a concern of a viewmodel. Show more of what your intent is.

Comment: Well there's some stuff that is happening in the viewmodel that I want to display toasts for depending on the result of those background processes.

Comment: I'm also trying to run the same statement in the page code and it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: You've included the right `css` files, right? <link href="_content/Blazored.Toast/blazored-toast.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Does the Button method work in your setup i.e. are you showing toasts on the page where you're using the view model when you add a button to the page and click it?  In other works is it working at all?

Comment: OK, somewhere in your UI you are calling/using the model. When it returns, show the toast. If it doesn't return, configure the model with an event you fire that the UI can handle.

Comment: Rereading this, you can't get the toast at all? Check the config. Did you add it to MainLayout, etc.? Any messages in the browser?

Comment: Well I can get the toast to appear with the correct styling using the technique shown in the documentation, but I need it to be called from the view model. Unless of course there are any other ways that people know of for creating javascript-free blazor toast.

Comment: You will need to show more code. You typically don't show UI elements from view models and libraries. You can interact with the UI when the call returns or you can raise an event that the UI reacts to.

Comment: Putting aside all the separation of concerns problems -`ToastService.ShowSuccess("Here is my message!")`is doing exactly what the button click does - it's triggering the `ToastService.OnShow` event which triggers the `BlazoredToasts` event handler (in `MainLayout`) and shows the toasts.  My only conclusion is we don't have the full picture here and we won't solve the problem without more code!

Comment: Alright, I'll edit my question. Bare with me.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your sample code I could make it work.  I suspect maybe you are missing the

```
<BlazoredToasts />
```

tag from the MainLayout.razor?

Here is my implementation...

**Page.razor**

```
@page "/"
@inject PageViewModel vm 
<button @onclick="() => Start()">Start</button>

@code {
    public void Start()
    {
        vm.Apply();
    }
}
```

**PageViewModel.cs**

```
using Blazored.Toast.Services;

namespace BlazoredToast2.Data
{
    public class PageViewModel
    {
        private Blazored.Toast.Services.ToastService _toastService;

        public PageViewModel(IToastService toast)
        {
            this._toastService = toast as Blazored.Toast.Services.ToastService;
        }

        public void Apply()
        {
            this._toastService.ShowSuccess("Here's a toast!");
            //If condition
            this._toastService.ShowSuccess("Condition 1");
            //Else condition
            this._toastService.ShowWarning("Condition 2");
        }
    }
}
```

**MainLayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<BlazoredToasts/>
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Host.cshtml**

```
...
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>BlazoredToast2</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazoredToast2.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazored.Toast/blazored-toast.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

And it looks like this:
[image]