Toast Component not working in Razor app C#
New to Blazor, kind of surprised there is no built in Dialog or Toast. Blazored-Toast to the rescue! Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. I suspect I am missing some critical step or some inclusion of some library, but I cannot identify it.
First what I have already looked at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69091643/blazored-toast-not-working-from-the-view-model#:~:text=1.%20I'm%20trying%20to%20get%20some%20toast%20to%20appear%20in
Also
https://github.com/Blazored/Toast/tree/main
Where I went thru the samples and the ReadMe.
I believe I have implemented everything but obviously not.
So here is the code:
MainLayout.Razor
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using Blazored.Toast;
@using Blazored.Toast.Services;
@using Blazored.Toast.Configuration

<BlazoredToasts Position="ToastPosition.TopRight"
                Timeout="10"
                ShowCloseButton="@true"
                MaxToastCount="3">
</BlazoredToasts>

Program.cs
using Blazored.Toast;
using MyStuff.Web;
using MyStuff.Web.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add service defaults & Aspire components.
builder.AddServiceDefaults();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddOutputCache();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredToast();
...

App.Razor
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="_content/Blazored.Toast/blazored-toast.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyStuff.Web.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

MyStuff.Razor
@using System.Data;
@using Blazored.Toast;
@using Blazored.Toast.Services;
@using Blazored.Toast.Configuration;
@attribute [StreamRendering(true)]
@attribute [OutputCache(Duration = 5)] 


<PageTitle>My STuff </PageTitle>

<h1>My Stuff</h1>

<p>Trying to get Blazored Toast to show up</p>

<EditForm Model="@batchModel">
    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@(() => ToastService.ShowSuccess("I'm a message trying to show Toast"))">Success Toast</button>
....

_Imports.razor
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OutputCaching
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using CollectXScore.Web
@using CollectXScore.Web.Components
@using Blazored.Toast
@using Blazored.Toast.Services

What happens is nothing no errors, nothing displayed when I click the button. Interestingly if I put in a timeout I can see the delay of the timeout (meaning it is doing something) but for some reason it does not display the toast. Perhaps I need to show how reference Material?

To be honest it looks like your code does not follow the instructions from the github page for blazored toast. Why not just start with doing exactly the things they tell you to do there?

The documentation says (pretty much the same as Radzen or MudBlazor) to "Add the <BlazoredToasts /> tag into your applications MainLayout.razor." this should be the definition of the component itself, put it down below all the razor code, at the root level (not nested). and include the usings in _Imports.razor. Hope this helps, and Wololoo my child.

@topsail Trying shoe horn it into my existing application, which does not have some of the items in the readme (Index.html for example). What I did do was go through the Samples and try to match as closely as possible to those samples, figuring they actually work (I have been tricked by out of date ReadMes before). Though maybe I am being tricked by the sample code?

@mrSoh Sry - I did do the changes to the _Imports.razor file. Have updated the question above.

Blazor interactive components registered in Layout require that your Blazor application [all of it] is interactive.
This line:
    <Routes />

means that your application is currently configured for Per Page/Component interactivity.  The Router and the Layout components, and with them BlazoredToasts, are statically rendered.  Which is why it won't work.
You need to enable Global Interactivity on Routes.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Blazr.ExploringServices.Web.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


Thank you! I would have never figured that out in a thousand years. Appreciate the help. One question - is that documented anywhere in the Blazored info and I missed it? Just curious. thanks again!

Not that I can see.  It is on most component library sites.   It's the answer to so many questions on here.

Awesome. I guess I can kick myself a little less since I am new to Blazor. Again appreciate your help!
